# NameError: name '...' is not defined

Tags: python-3.6, keras

Пытаюсь загрузить модель, в которой использовалась loss функция написанная вручную и при попытке загрузить использую параметр custom_objects, но аутпут выдает ошибку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
model = load_model("gdrive/My Drive/my_model.h5", custom_objects = {'class_loss_cls_fixed_num': class_loss_cls_fixed_num})
```

Comment: Функция у вас называется `class_loss_cls_fixed_num` или как-то по-другому?

Comment: @insolor да, именно так

Comment: Эта функция "видна" коду из этой строки? Добавьте больше кода.

Comment: @insolor я просто загружаю модель натренированную прежде

Comment: Допустим. Но если код не видит функцию, которую в параметрах передаете, то код не запустится.

Comment: @insolor ну я добавила ее в тот же ноутбук и судя по всему никак не видит

Comment: Значит ячейку с функцией в ноутбуке нужно выполнить.